# Can i set "accept incoming connection" option for Apple Remote Desktop (ARD)?

Tags: macos, security, remote-desktop

We already use Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) for Admin > User connections for admin / tech support sessions. In this instance we **DO NOT** require the User to confirm acceptance for the ARD session.

We also want to use it for User > User connections for collaborations / meetings. In this instance we **DO** require the User to confirm acceptance for the ARD session.

Is it possible to set ARD on the receiving computer to require the local user to authenticate / accept the connection ?

Comment: I had a poke at this after your earlier question. It does seem [though I'm open to correction] that "Screen Sharing" & ARD are almost mutually exclusive. Once you set Remote Management, the peer-to-peer aspect seems to be lost. I'm guessing a bit because I don't want to have to break down my ARD structure to investigate fully.

Comment: @Tetsujin You are correct - there is no “both” here - just automating a change to the settings with `kickstart` to alter the behavior just in time for the non-prompted control event.

Answer (score 1):

We set the user default on all machines and then automate changing it right before an IT / Admin connection needs to be made and then reset the default after the support engagement.

The command you need to craft is two versions of `kickstart` and then your admin can send the less restrictive command over ssh/ARD, then screen connect, then rest the default after using ssh/ARD remote command.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201710